# How to get all of those products which are selected in two parent categories?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, database, configurable-product

How to i can get products from 1 specific category because my products are checked in two parent category. for example
(I have product with the name of xyz and my categories name are A & B, Now i want get products from B which products also checked in A)
If products is selected in category A & category B then show all of those products. I hope you can understand what i mean. please help me, Thansk in advance. (Magento 1.9.2 - Configurable Products)

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('neq' => 0));
$products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','configurable');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
$products->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('description');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('url');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 250));
$products->addAttributeToSelect('special_price');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
$products->joinField('category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    'category_id',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    null,
    'left'
);

$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('149','224')));
foreach ($products as $product) {
   echo $product->getName();
   print_r($product);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this bit of code and answer is also linked over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21480000/8164643)

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('neq' => 0));
$products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
$products->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('description');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('url');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 250));
$products->addAttributeToSelect('special_price');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
$products->joinField('category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    'category_id',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    null,
    'left'
);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(32,5)));
foreach ($products as $product) {

}
```

Comment: you are using condition in of both categories in this line ?

$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(32,5)));

Comment: yes they are both category's ids

Comment: I have put same code only replace cat id's, but not showing, i think your code is for simple products but i have configurable products ? and which code i'll be write in foreach loop ?

Comment: Are you getting the product collection. just print the product collection. you must get some product collection.

Comment: Still not working i think error in this section

$products->joinField('category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    'category_id',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    null,
    'left'
);

Comment: i'm printing products collection like as 
   echo $product->getName();
   print_r($product);

but getting blank screen http://www.fakhruddinsouq.com/mostv

Comment: can you please describe me this line ?
addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 250))

Comment: It's for products whose price is greater than 250